# List comprehension iterate two variables at the same time

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is it possible that with the use of list comprehension to iterate through two variables at the same time increasing the loop position in both at the same time. See example below:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

b = [6,7,8,9,10]

c = [i+j for i in a for j in b] # This works but the output is not what it would be expected.
```

expected output is `c = [7, 9, 11, 13, 15]` (n'th element from a + n'th element from b)

Thank you.

Comment: Try this: `c = [i+j for i,j in zip(a,b)]`

Answer (score 13):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,10]

c = map(sum, zip(a, b))
print c

#Output
[7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```

Comment: While this is completely valid, using the sum function is unnecessarily complicated for a newbie. The other problem is that in Python 3 this returns a map object - e.g. `<map object at 0x0000019B59329DA0>`

While `map` is faster, the following is simpler...

```python
c = [aa + bb  for  aa, bb in zip(a,b)]
```