# List of comprehension on multiple variables in order to concatenate into a list of strings the results

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists.
I would like to concatenate in order to get a list of strings.
The first list is composed of strings
The second list is composed of a Timestamp.

I would concatenate as follow in one line with a list of comprehension.

```
#just for creating something similar to my actual situation
import pandas as pd
quarter=["First Quarter","Second Quarter","Third Quarter","Fourth Quarter"]
quarter_forecast_day=pd.date_range(start="12/15/2020",periods=4)
```

I would like something like that:

```
str(quarter[x]+'\n'+quarter_forecast[y].strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

What I tried:

```
#quarter_label=[str(quarter[x]+'\n'+y.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")) for x,y in [quarter, quarter_forecast_day]]
#too many values to unpack (expected 2)

#quarter_label=[str(quarter[x]+'\n'+y.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")) for x,y in (quarter, quarter_forecast_day)]
#too many values to unpack (expected 2)

#quarter_label=[str(quarter[x]+'\n'+y.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")) for x,y in quarter, quarter_forecast_day]
#invalid sintax

#quarter_label=[lambda x,y:str(quarter[x]+'\n'+y.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") for x,y in [quarter, quarter_forecast]]
#invalid sintax

quarter_label=[lambda x,y:str(quarter[x]+'\n'+y.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") for x,y in (quarter, quarter_forecast)]
#invalid sintax
```

Before asking I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351085/multiple-variables-in-list-comprehension), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269538/list-comprehension-iterate-two-variables-at-the-same-time) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269538/list-comprehension-iterate-two-variables-at-the-same-time). But I am still struggling to find a proper way to apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with zip:

```
quarter_label = [q+'\n'+qf.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") for q, qf in zip(quarter, quarter_forecast_day)]

>>> print(quarter_label)

['First Quarter\n15/12/2020', 'Second Quarter\n16/12/2020', 'Third Quarter\n17/12/2020', 'Fourth Quarter\n18/12/2020']
```

Comment: I was curious to understand why `\n` is read as `\n` and not as a command to start a new line? 
About this point, I was not explicit in my question, because I was not aware that It will return a character I was sure about "Start New Line" command.

Comment: `'\n'` is a "Start New Line" command, but when printing the list, the `repr` of the strings is printed and not the `str`. To see the newline, do something like `for s in quarter_label: print(s)`. Also, see this SO question about [the difference between `__repr__` and `__str__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/14160477).

Comment: @RoyCohen wow it works when I do ´[print(s) for s in quarter_label ]´  And It was something I did not know!

Answer (score 1):

First, the `str()` is not needed as you are concatenating 3 strings (`strftime` returns a string).

Second, for a double variable comprehension list, you need to use two `for` loops, as followed:

```py
quarter_label = [quarter[x] + '\n' + quarter_forecast[y] for x in range(len(quarter)) for y in range(len(quarter_forecast))]
```

The problem with your code is that you're iterating on the items of the list, but you're using them as indices in the expression. With an item iteration:

```py
quarter_label = [q + '\n' + f for q in quarter for f in quarter_forecast]
```

Results:

```
['First Quarter\n15/12/2020', 'First Quarter\n16/12/2020', 'First Quarter\n17/12/2020', 'First Quarter\n18/12/2020', 'Second Quarter\n15/12/2020', 'Second Quarter\n16/12/2020', 'Second Quarter\n17/12/2020', 'Second Quarter\n18/12/2020', 'Third Quarter\n15/12/2020', 'Third Quarter\n16/12/2020', 'Third Quarter\n17/12/2020', 'Third Quarter\n18/12/2020', 'Fourth Quarter\n15/12/2020', 'Fourth Quarter\n16/12/2020', 'Fourth Quarter\n17/12/2020', 'Fourth Quarter\n18/12/2020']
```

Comment: I don't think it'll work. When using two for loops inside a list comprehension it's like having two nested for loops, the output will be every possible pair of `q` and `f`. I think the right solution is the one using `zip`.

Comment: depends on what the OP is looking for, I'll add the result in my answer so that they know immediatey what the code does.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Luc :) The variable quarter_forecast is a TimeStamp is not a String, I have to convert first to a string. I used now `pd.date_range(start="12/15/2020",periods=4)` for creating the example, in my original case I have another TimeStamp datatype and I have to concatenate with a string.  :)